# How to read program arguments

Tags: c

I am suppose to read the number of thread requested by the client. So if someone run my program like this:

```
./test 2
```

I have to read the number of thread equal to 2. I try `getchar()` but it's not working. Any idea?

Comment: In this case the 2 is being passed as an argument to the program.  Try searching for information about processing arguments in a C program.

Comment: I have an idea for you — read at least some book on C programming...

Comment: I tried argv[0], but it cannot read "2"

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371886/command-line-arguments-in-c

Comment: `argv[0]` always contains the program name invoked by the command. Thus, the first _real_ argument is stored in `argv[1]`. But you have to check if such an argument exist. To do so, just read `argc`, it tells you the number of elements pointed by `argv`. In your case, it should equal 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with threads per se.

The first argument to your program, if given, will be found in `argv[1]` but as a string, so you need to turn it into an integer with something like `atoi` or `strtol`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a minimal example with complete, correct error checking and diagnostic messages.  Note that setting `errno` to 0 is necessary for distinguishing range errors from valid `strtoul()` outputs, this is an annoying quirk of the function.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        fputs("usage: test NTHREAD\n", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }
    char *e;
    errno = 0;
    unsigned long nthread = strtoul(argv[1], &e, 0);
    if (!*argv[1] || *e) {
        fputs("error: invalid NTHREAD\n", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }
    if (nthread == (unsigned long) -1 && errno == ERANGE) {
        fputs("error: NTHREAD out of range\n", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }
    // Your code goes here
}
```

Comment: Won't errno be zero to start with?

Comment: @paxdiablo: I put `errno = 0` in order to allow the block of code to be copied and pasted into sections where the precondition `errno == 0` is not guaranteed.  It also means that people reading the code do not have to examine surrounding code to verify the precondition.

Comment: Fair point, that makes sense.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand, but I don't think this is valid C (although it might be OK for a C++ sample) because C requires all variable declarations to occur before any code (so the declarations of `*e` and `nthread` would cause errors)...

Comment: @neilr8133: You are referring to an obsolete version of the C standard.  The C standard has allowed such declarations since 1999, and widespread compiler support for the feature is older than that.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Sorry about that: when I use `-Wall -ansi -pedantic` on my sample program (gcc version 3.4.4 (cygming special, gdc 0.12, using dmd 0.125)) I get `warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code`..guess it's defaulting to a much older standard.  Thanks for the update!

Comment: @neilr8133: From the GCC documentation: "`-ansi`: In C mode, this is equivalent to `-std=c90`."  GCC actually defaults to something called "gnu90" and Clang defaults to a language based on C99.  Both compilers use defaults that allow mixed declarations and code, and both compilers support newer standards by specifying them directly using `-std=c99` or `-std=c11`.  Support is incomplete, but I strongly advise against using the `-ansi` flag since it enables trigraphs, and you almost certainly don't want to enable trigraphs.  I recommend either `-std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` (or `-std=gnu99`)

Answer (score 2):

`int main(int argc, int **argv)`

Using arguments of `main`, you should know the first argument `argv[0]` is the name of current executing file, and the following arguments are the parameters sent to your program.

In your case, you must read `argv[1]`.

Always check `argc` to count the entered arguments.