# How can I call with a int function in main function?

Tags: c, linux

I have a requirement to insert something in the function main > my_isneg to call my_isneg function. How can I do it?

```
#include <unistd.h>
void my_putchar (char c)
{
    write (1, &c, 1);
}
int my_isneg (int n)
{

    if (n < 0) {
        my_putchar (78); }
    else {
        my_putchar (80);
    }
}

int main (void)
{
    my_isneg();
}
```

Comment: The name of your function is not `my_inseg` but `my_isneg` and it does a `my_putchar` of either the letter `N` (negative) or `P` (positive). What is that `my_putchar` and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read this: [ask]. It's totally unclear what you're asking. What is the `my_isneg` supposed to do? You call `my_isneg()` without parameter, this is wrong and pointless. What do the numbers 78 and 80 represent?

Comment: the 78 and 80 are for the ASCII table, and I want that print that if execute tell me that if the number is positive print P and if negative N

Comment: @Jonathan rather than looking up the ASCII table and writing `78` or `80` let the C compiler do the work for you and write `'N'` and `'P' `

Comment: @Jabberwocky but how wihout using number in main, just when u exexcute (./a.out 5), I don't how to call the function main >my_isneg to my_isneg

Comment: @Jonathan your last comment totally changes your question. You should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371886/command-line-arguments-in-c), but this implies converting a string into a number which might be beyond your scope for the moment. Hint: the [`atol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atol/) may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's somewhat unclear what you're asking, but maybe you want this:

```
...
// print 'N' 1 if the number n is strictly negative, print 'P' otherwise
int my_isneg(int n)
{
  if (n < 0) {
    my_putchar('N');  // use 'N' instead of 80 (it's more readable)
  }
  else {
    my_putchar('P');  // use 'P' instead of 80
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  my_isneg(-1);
  my_isneg(1);
  my_isneg(2);
}
```

Output

```
NPP
```

Or maybe this, which matches the name `my_isneg` more closely:

```
...
// return 1 if the number n is strictly negative
int my_isneg(int n)
{
  return n < 0;
}

int main(void)
{
  if (my_isneg(-1))
    my_putchar('N');
  else
    my_putchar('P');

  if (my_isneg(1))
    my_putchar('N');
  else
    my_putchar('P');
}
```

Output

```
NP
```