# Command line argument validation in C

Tags: c, int

I have a program that needs to get an `int` from the user from the command line

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

My only problem is that I need to check whether `argv` is an `int`. If it isn't, I need to return an error. How can I do that? I have to check if the input is an `int` before using `atoi`. Can someone help me?

Comment: `char* argv[]` is an array of pointers to string. None of them is an `int`, although it could be numeric. You have to convert it yourself.

Comment: Is there any way I can discover if it is numeric before the conversion? If I try to convert it and it isn't numeric my program will crash, so I wanted to discover it before converting

Comment: Validation tests include 1) argc big enough? 2) with `strtol(argv[]...)` did conversion occur?, trailing non-numeric text? in range of `int`?  3) Pedantic details include if leading/trailing white-space allowed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command line arguments in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371886/command-line-arguments-in-c)

Answer (score 8):

Here's one way, using `strtol` and checking the end of the string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char *cp;
    long lval;
    int val;

    // skip over program name
    --argc;
    ++argv;

    if (argc < 1) {
        fprintf(stderr,"main: no argument specified\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    cp = *argv;
    if (*cp == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"main: argument an empty string\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    lval = strtol(cp,&cp,10);
    if (*cp != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"main: argument '%s' is not an integer -- '%s'\n",
            *argv,cp);
        exit(1);
    }

    val = (int) lval;

    // NOTE: just going for extra credit here ;-)
    // ensure number fits in a int (since strtol returns long and that's 64
    // bits on a 64 bit machine)
#if 1
    if (val != lval) {
        fprintf(stderr,"main: argument '%s' (with value %ld) is too large to fit into an integer -- truncated to %d\n",
            *argv,lval,val);
        exit(1);
    }
#endif

    printf("val=%d\n",val);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Minor: Code does not detect conversion overflow of strtol() Code incorrectly assumes range of long more than int. If same range, `if (val != lval)` is always true. Suggest looking at `errno, INT_MAX,INT_MIN`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char *cp;
    long lval;
    int val;

    // skip over program name
    --argc;
    ++argv;

    if (argc < 1) {
        fprintf(stderr,"main: no argument specified\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    cp = *argv;
    if (*cp == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"main: argument an empty string\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    errno = 0;
    lval = strtol(cp,&cp,10);

    if (*cp != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"main: argument '%s' is not an integer -- '%s'\n",
            *argv,cp);
        exit(1);
    }

    // on a 32 bit machine, entering 2147483648 will produce a non-zero errno
    if (errno) {
        fprintf(stderr,"main: argument '%s' parse error -- '%s'\n",
            *argv,strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    // on a 64 bit machine, entering 2147483648 will not produce an error, so
    // we should check the range ourselves
    if ((lval < INT_MIN) || (lval > INT_MAX)) {
        fprintf(stderr,"main: argument '%s' range error -- %ld outside of range (%ld to %ld)\n",
            *argv,lval,(long) INT_MIN,(long) INT_MAX);
        exit(1);
    }

    val = (int) lval;

    // NOTE: just going for extra credit here ;-)
    // ensure number fits in a int (since strtol returns long and that's 64
    // bits on a 64 bit machine)
    // FIXME -- with above tests this can never be true (i.e. fault), so
    // I've nop'ed it -- left in to show prior/original test
#if 0
    if (val != lval) {
        fprintf(stderr,"main: argument '%s' (with value %ld) is too large to fit into an integer -- truncated to %d\n",
            *argv,lval,val);
        exit(1);
    }
#endif

    printf("val=%d\n",val);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Minor: Code does not detect conversion overflow of `strtol()`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I'd be glad to add a check, but I'm not sure what you mean. If I had to hazard a guess, would this be specifying (e.g.) a large positive int value that is > `INT_MAX` causing a rollover to a negative value?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I've edited [and tested] to check `errno` and `INT_MIN/INT_MAX` range.

Comment: Nice improvement.  With improvement `if (val != lval)` is never true.

Comment: Good enough without overflow check. It's not typical to pass such big numbers via command line parameters.

Answer (score 4):

> Command line argument validation in C

> I need to check whether argv is an int

1. Test first if `argv[]` contains a string by checking `argc`.

```
    for (int a = 1; a < argc; a++) {
      int_validation(argv[a]);
    }
```

2. Attempt conversion using `strtol()`

```
#include <ctype.h> 
#include <errno.h> 
#include <limits.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 

void int_validation(const char *s) {
  // If leading space not OK
  // isspace() only valid in unsigned char range and EOF.
  if (isspace(*(unsigned char *)s)) {
    puts("Fail - leading spaces");
    return;
  }

  // Convert
  int base = 0;  // Use 10 for base 10 only input
  char *endptr;
  errno = 0;
  long val = strtol(s, &endptr, base);

  if (s == endptr) { // When endptr is same as s, no conversion happened.
    puts("Fail - no conversion");
    return;
  }      
 
  // detect overflow
  if (errno == ERANGE || val < INT_MIN || val > INT_MAX) {
    errno = ERANGE;
    puts("Fail - overflow");
    return;
  }      

  // If trailing space OK, seek pass them
  while (isspace(*(unsigned char *)endptr)) {
    endptr++;
  }

  // If trailing non-numeric text bad
  if (*endptr) {
    puts("Fail - overflow");
    return;
  }

  printf("Success %d\n", (int) val);
  return;
}
```

Adjust return type and messages as desired.

---

Typically input like `"1e5"` or `"123.0"`, although  mathematically a whole number, is not consider valid `int` input.  Additional code needed to allow those.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to convert the argument using `strtol()`, it will return `0` if the value is not parseable or the parsed value.

You can also use the second argument for a more detailed verification of the input, you can differenciate between a bad input or a `0` input, since in both cases the returned value is `0`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long parsed_value = 0;
    int value = 0;
    //for  command + 1 argument
    if (argc == 2)
    {    
        errno = 0;
        char *end_ptr;
        parsed_value = strtol(argv[1], &end_ptr, 10);
        //argument check, overflow, trailing characters, underflow,  errno 
        if(*end_ptr == argv[1][0] || *end_ptr != '\0' || errno == ERANGE 
            || parsed_value < INT_MIN || parsed_value > INT_MAX){
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid argument");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    else{
        fprintf(stderr, "Wrong number of arguments, %d provided, 2 needed", argc);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    //otherwise the value was parsed correctly
    value = parsed_value;
    printf("%d", value);
}
```

Comment: Oh, thx, that actually works. The program doesn't need to process the value 0 because it would be useless in this context. Thanks

Comment: `strtol` provides other mechanisms for detecting error.  Specifically the `endptr` argument, which will point to the first invalid character.  If endptr is equal to the start of your string and not `NULL`, then you know that the string was not an integer.

Comment: Minor: Code does not detect conversion overflow of `strtol()`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, question, do you really need to set errno to 0?

Comment: Given this is `main()`, `errno` can be assumed to be 0, but not in a general `int_validation(char *s)` test due to unknown prior history.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica IMO it's a bad habit to ever write code assuming `errno` is zero at any point.  Inserting a debug `[f]printf()` can break that assumption.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Agree that coding `errno = 0;` is best prior to the `strto*()` call.

Comment: When `errno` serves as the indicator that an error occured, then set it to 0 first.  If there is another indicator that unambiguously tells you there is an error that prompts you to check `errno`, then you are fine to not set it to 0 first.  In this case, `errno` does serve as an indicator that an error occurred, so it should be set to zero first.

Comment: Best to test `errno` _before_ other function calls.  `!isdigit(*end_ptr)` looks wrong.  Did you want `*end_ptr != '\0'`?.   This code uses `errno > 0` when overflow detection is `errno == ERANGE`.  Not bad - yet different.  Perhaps `errno != 0`?  _Some_ implementations will set `errno` to other codes when other problems detected like when `strtol(s,...)` and `s==NULL` - which should not occur here.

Answer (score 1):

Use `isdigit` to test the characters of the argument for "digit-ness", then convert it (or not) based on the results. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool is_all_digits(char *s)
{
    bool b = true;

    for( ; *s ; ++s)
        if(!isdigit(*s))
        {
            b = false;
            break;
        }

    return b;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < argc ; ++i)
    {
        if(is_all_digits(argv[i]))
            printf("argv[%d] is an integer = %d\n", i, atoi(argv[i]));
        else
            printf("argv[%d] is not an integer \"%s\"\n", i, argv[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When run with the command-line arguments

```
123 "Not a number" 456.789 "Not another number" 10
```

the following output is produced:

```
argv[0] is not an integer "./a.out"
argv[1] is an integer = 123
argv[2] is not an integer "Not a number"
argv[3] is not an integer "456.789"
argv[4] is not an integer "Not another number"
argv[5] is an integer = 10
```

As others have noted, `is_all_digits` doesn't guarantee that a string which represents an integer is parse-able using `atoi` or any other routine, but feel free to doctor this to your heart's content. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to [`strtol()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) (that is the *canonical answer*) you can perform an *hand made* validation by using [`isdigit()` function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isdigit.htm), and also checking for *leading sign characters* (`+` and `-`):

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <bool.h>

bool isValidInteger( char * str )
{
    bool ret = true;

    if( str )
    {
        char p = str;

        for( int i=0; str[i] != 0; i++ )
        {
            if ( !isdigit( str[i] ) )
            {
                if( i == 0 && ( str[i] == '+' || *p == '-' ) && str[i+1] )
                    continue;
                ret = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

This implementation relies on the fact that input string is null terminated. But since every `argv[N]` is a null terminated string, we are fine.

Usage:

```
if ( isValidInteger( argv[1] ) )
{
    int par = atoi( argv[1] );
}
```

Note (1): this validator doesn't check against input values that exceed the `int` range (from `INT_MIN` to `INT_MAX`). This is a limitation that might be considered acceptable in many cases.

---

Note (2): this function doesn't trim leading spaces like `strto*` do. If such feature is required, a check like this one can be added at the top of the `for-loop`:

```
bool flag = true;

if( str[i] == ' ' )
    continue;

flag = false;
```

In this way spaces will be tolerated, but only until `flag` is set to `false` that is when the first non-space character is encountered.

Comment: Just checking that every character is a digit is not sufficient.  Leading `+` and `-` signs are also part of valid strings that represent numbers that `atoi()` has the capability to convert.  But you also have to validate that the value that the string of digits represent can fit into an `int` in order to avoid undefined behavior. So to safely use `atoi()` on unknown input without invoking undefined behavior, you have to parse the full string and verify that `INT_MIN <= value <= INT_MAX`. You have to fully solve the problem before you can safely use `atoi()` to solve the problem.

Comment: @AndrewHenle for some reasons I forgotten the sign chars. I fixed at least that. You are right also about INT_MIN / INT_MAX check: about it I'll add a note declaring it as a limitation (imho acceptable in most cases).

Comment: @AndrewHenle I though about a string len check inside validator (that must be less than 11), an external conversion with `atol`, and a casting to the target integer. But it was too much for an answer starting with the assertion that strtol was the right choice... from a phone. Especially since a similar implementation would have raised issues about the integer size in the current platform. Too much :)

Comment: Note that `strto*()` allows leading white-space unlike `isValidInteger()` -  Better or worse depending on goals.

Comment: @chux this is correct too. But in this scenario I think that wouldn't matter since cmdline parser _trims_ leading spaces while building `argv`. Not sure about what happens for a parameter such as `"     1235`".

Comment: @RobertoCaboni the cmdline parser usually is expected to trims WS, yet an `exec()` call does not.  IAC, a minor diff.

Comment: @chux ... nevertheless I added a note for a possible implementation of WS trimming (externally, since it is a secondary feature). Please, stop finding flaws of my poor admittedly suboptimal function.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I'll let you sort error messaging however you like:

```
#define TRUE  1
#define FALSE 0

int is_integer( char *s )
{
  int i = 0 ;
  int is_digit;
  int is_sign;

  while ( s[i] != '\0' )
  {
    // this test makes the assumption that the code points for
    // decimal digits are contiguous. True for ASCII/UNICODE and EBCDIC.
    // If you're using some other bizarro encoding, you're out of luck.

    is_digit = s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9' ? TRUE : FALSE ;
    is_sign  = i == 0 && s[i] == '-'      ? TRUE : FALSE ;

    if ( !is_digit && !is_sign )
    {
      return FALSE;
    }

    ++i;
  }

  return TRUE;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  int  i    = 0    ;
  int  cc   = 0    ; // assume success;

  for ( i = 0 ; i < argc ; ++i )
  {
    if ( !is_integer(argv[i]) )
    {
      cc  = 1;
    }
  }

  return cc; // exit code 0 is success; non-zero exit code is failure.
}
```

Comment: "makes the assumption that the code points for
    // decimal digits are contiguous." --> No assumption needed. C requires that.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: fixed it for you.

Comment: Is `while ( s[i] != '\0' )...` missing an `i++`?