# the gets_s function in C language

Tags: c, function, gets

I wrote a test program, in this progtam there is a menu function, which allows user to choose a thing he wants to do. And there is a thing, if he chooses a task, where function `gets_s` is located and when, for example, user wants a task 2, he writes 2 and then presses "enter" and then the function `gets_s` thinks that this "enter" is for it and then my program finishes.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
 
void test() 
{ 
    char str[25]; 
    gets_s(str, 24); 
    printf("%s\n", str); 
} 
int menu() 
{ 
    int choice; 
    printf("Choose a task\n1 - task 1\n else...\n"); 
    scanf_s("%d", &choice); 
    return choice; 
} 
int main(void) 
{ 
    int x; 
    x = menu(); 
    if (x == 1) 
    test(); 
}
```

You can try this program and see that after your input 1, the program will finish. I don't understand why this happens, how can i do it without finishing the program?

Comment: This is a classic problem of formatted vs unformatted input. You used `scanf_s` to read an integer (the `1`). When you typed “1” you _also_ pressed ENTER. `scanf_s` read the integer, but not the ENTER (newline). Then, you try using `gets_s`, which reads the (as yet unread) ENTER and properly terminates.

Comment: My general advice is to read _all_ user input as a string and then use things like `sscanf` to get information out of the string.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. And how to avoid this?

Comment: Don't mix formatted and unformatted functions. Read a whole line with fgets and parse it accordingly.

Comment: Note: Kr1sp0, `-1` not needed.  `gets_s(str, 24);` --> `gets_s(str, 25);` or even better as `gets_s(str, sizeof str);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User input is significantly more difficult than people generally to think it is (or ought to be).

I personally find that a little helper function works, such as one to get an integer from the user. Here is one such way:

```
int ask_integer( const char * prompt )
{
  // Prompt the user for input
  if (prompt)
    printf( "%s", prompt );

  // Get user’s answer as a string ending with ENTER key press
  char s[100];
  if (!fgets( s, sizeof(s), stdin ))
    complain_and_quit();

  char * first = skipws( s );           // (skip over any leading whitespace)
  if (!*first) complain_and_quit();     // (nothing but whitespace == error)

  char * last = strchr( first, '\n' );  // (find the newline/ENTER)
  if (!last) complain_and_quit();       // (not found == line too long == error)
  *last = '\0';                         // (strip the newline)

  // Convert user’s input to an integer, if possible
  errno = 0;
  long n = strtol( first, &last, 10 );
  if (errno or (n < INT_MIN) or (n > INT_MAX))
    complain_and_quit();                // (out of range == error)

  last = skipws( last );                // (skip over any trailing whitespace)
  if (*last) complain_and_quit();       // (fail if input not JUST an integer)

  return n;
}
```

With

```
char * skipws( char * s )
{
  while (isspace( (unsigned char)(*s) )) ++s;
  return s;
}
```

Notice that there are a lot of things to check *just to get an integer*. Yes, it is obnoxious.

The method you use to handle errors is up to you. For most schoolwork assignments, any variation of a simple “complain and quit” is sufficient.

Notice the pattern:

1. Obtain an entire line of input
2. Attempt to validate/convert/process that input

The using code is now much simpler:

```
int menu(void)
{
  return ask_integer(
    "Menu:\n"
    "  1 - Quux\n"
    "  2 - Frob\n"
    "  ...\n"
    "? " );
}

int main(void)
{
  switch (menu())
  {
    case 1: test(); break;
    ...
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Or, using `if`:

```
int main(void)
{
  int choice = menu();
  if (choice == 1)
    test();
  else if (...)
    ...;
  else
    ...;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: String to integer conversion is not bad, yet has some troubles.  If the `long` value is outside the `int` range, no  detection of that problem.  If the text is outside `long` range, again, no detection.  Pedantic: if the first character read is a `'\n'` or a _null character_, no detection of error.  If `*p < 0`, `isspace(*p)` is UB.  Still likely OK as is for OP's learning.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica All true. (This is what always happens when I just type something in off the top of my head, alas.) Also fixed to check the return value from `fgets()` (but without any care as to _why_ it may have failed, whether it be EOF or something else). Not fixed: if input includes an embedded nul then it is considered mal-formed, even if it is otherwise correct. Sorry it took so long for me to get back to this.

Comment: You may like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62293329/2410359).

Comment: Very clean! Having little functions like that make doing stuff _so_ much easier

Answer (score 0):

If by "without finishing," you mean you want your program to repeat accepting user input and taking appropriate action, you need a loop around your main logic:

```
int x = 0;
while (x >= 0) {
    x = menu(); 
    if (x == 1) 
        test(); 
    else if (x ==2) 
        test2();
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: Alas, you misread the OP’s code.

Comment: That's possible, which is why I qualified my answer. But the OP did indicate that the program was not to terminate, and the most straightforward way to achieve this is with a loop. Properly parsing the input is another matter. But, I could be mistaken as to the OP's intent.

Comment: Yes, I often misread what people mean. (I must be more lucid ATM than usual.) OP indicated he program was terminating _early_, not that it wasn’t looping.